# Facebook OpenGraph: Getting like count of post without User Token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have an existing app that uses the Facebook API & login that makes posts to the user's wall. For each post I store the id of that post.

What I need to accomplish is to gather like counts of those posts generated by the first app. I'm trying to write a small app that routinely pulls the like count. I've figured out how to get the like count of the post if I use a User Token - via Facebook Login. But since this app will run as a batch and not by a human, I don't want to use a Facebook login page. I could write code that simulates a user logging in but that would be a major ugly hack. I've tried to use an App Token but then the like count is always zero. I've found how to get the like count of a page without the need for a User Token http://www.techrecite.com/get-facebook-likes-count-of-a-page-using-graph-api/ but not a post

Is this even possible? If so how?

I've looked into Facebook API's subscription, but it doesn't seem possible to subscribe to a "like-a-post" event. Although I could be wrong. If so, could someone point me in the correct direction.

Thanks.

Comment: it would not just be an "ugly hack", it would be illegal to simulate a user login ;) - anyway, i am pretty sure it´s not possible, even with a user token - because you would need "read_stream", and it will not get approved by facebook. so you could only use it for your own profile.

Comment: You will not be able to read the likes of a post with anything else but a user token, if that post is not public. You would need `read_stream` permission of the post owner for that (and use of that you will most likely not get granted in permission review).